# The number of ways to paint 3 cubes using 3 cans of paint, so that two cubes are blue

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question about the usage of the probability formula (I believe that is what it is called).

So, I have 3 cubes and 3 differently colored cans of paint (Let's say, Red, Yellow and Blue). I am going to paint each cube 1 color; however, I want to know what the total number of possible combinations are. In addition, I want to know how many of those combinations involve 2 of the cubes being Blue.

I could solve this by writing out all 27 combinations and then counting, but I'm pretty sure there is a formula to avoid that involving factorials?

To Solve:

Since I have 3 objects (cubes) and 3 possible outcomes for each (cans of paints), 3^3 tells me that there are 27 possible combinations.

That is about as far as I got. I believe the proper formula is something to the effect of n! / (n-k)! ??

Answer (score 0):

If exactly $2$ cubes are blue ($B$), then exactly $1$ cube is non-blue ($N$). In how many ways can we arrange $2$ blue cubes and $1$ non-blue cube in a row? Well that would be:
$$
\binom{3}{1} = {}_3C_1 = \frac{3!}{1!2!} = 3
$$
Indeed, they are:
$$
BBN, BNB, NBB
$$
Now for each of these arrangements, we must assign either red or yellow to each non-blue cube. For a fixed arrangement, this can be done in $2$ ways. So our grand total is:
$$
3 \cdot 2 = 6
$$

Comment: So 6 is the number of permutations derived from 3!/1! (n!/(n-k)!)? 

If I edited the problem to be a much larger amount of cubes and colors: Say-

7 cubes, 5 colors, (Red, Green, Yellow, Blue, White)-- I want to know the 1) Number of possible combinations 2) Number of combinations which involve 3 cubes being blue 3) Number of permutations involving 3 cubes being blue. 

Would I then solve the problem like this?

7^5 = 16807 possible combinations 

7!/(4!)(3!) = 35 combinations where 3 are blue

7!/4! = 210 permutations? (BBBWW, BBBWR, BBBRW)... etc. 

Trying to drive the point home!

Comment: It's true that there would be $\frac{7!}{3!4!}$ combinations where $3$ are blue. Now pick a combination and imagine assigning the other $5 - 1 = 4$ non-blue colours to each of the $7 - 3 = 4$ non-blue cubes. This can be done in $4^4$ ways, for a grand total of:
$$
\frac{7!}{3!4!} \cdot 4^4 = 35 \cdot 256 = 8960
$$
ways.